# PHP sign out with session issue

Tags: php, session

I've two logout.php pages with session. 1 is for user panel and other is admin panel. So that I used following code to sign out.

**For Admin logout.**

```
<?php
include("include/session.php");
include("db.php");
unset($_SESSION['uname_ad']);
?>
```

**For user logout**

```
<?php
include("include/session.php");
include("db.php");
unset($_SESSION['uname']);
?>
```

So is it secure sign out with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd destroy the entire session...

`session_destroy();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Daid Nguyen. But If i use session_destroy() then both of variable will destroy. So that both user and admin is logged out.

Comment: Why on earth would they be treated separately?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can also use

```
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
```

Comment: Always call `exit;` after a header `Location` redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little safer to use a different session_name for both your admin and user sessions.  That way you can destroy an entire user/admin session and not effect the other.

It will use a separate cookie for admin vs user, and you can be logged in simultaneously as an admin and a user yet the two sessions will be isolated from eachother.

See [session_name()](http://php.net/session_name)

Comment: if i destroy the session with session_destroy() then both variable is destroy. So that both user and admin is logged out. How do i make it to separate

Comment: Technically since you would be changing the session name between admin and user sessions, only one would be in use at a time.  So if you were in admin using session_name('admin'), the session_destroy() only destroys the admin session name because it is active.  The other is left alone.

Answer (score 0):

You should always [regenerate the session identifier](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) when changing user privileges, so if you're going to maintain both admin and user session data within the same session, you should regenerate the identifier when one or the other logs out.

Comment: @user1161867: Try it yourself.  Do a little research.  If you still can't figure it out, show us what you tried and what doesn't work and we'll help you out.

Comment: in other words, destroy and recreate the session

Comment: @AdamSack:  That is not what regenerating means.  Look at `session_regenerate_id()`.  It simply changes the current session identifier.  If you pass `TRUE` as an argument, it will delete the old session data, but the session is neither destroyed nor recreated.  It just gets copied to a new identifier.

Comment: theres not reason to regenerate the session ID, it just pisses other programmers of that work with your scripts.

Comment: @AdamSack:  I suggest you read about session-based attacks and security in general.